# VS Code doesn't acknowledge .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I updated my vscode and the debugger stopped working for .net core. Omnisharp doesn't start. Omnisharp log is empty. If I try to run and debug, it says that I don't have extensions for dbugging C#, though I have. When I try to create the launch.json file, it doesn't show .net core in the environments. I have already reinstalled .net core SDK and the runtime and vscode multiple times. Nothing seems to work.

I have attached the extension installed and the empty Omnisharp log
[image: C# extension installed and the omnisharp log]

[image: .NET Core not being an option in the environments]

Comment: Maybe C# extension is downloading latest Omnisharp? Do you see in 'Command Palette' any 'Omnisharp ... ' commands (i.e. Omnisharp: Restart Omnsharp)?

Comment: It says the **Command 'OmniSharp: Restart OmniSharp' resulted in an error (command 'o.restart' not found)**

Comment: Check 'omnisharp.path' in 'settings.json' - it should be empty. If not, clear it and restart VSCode to force C# to download omnisharp. If it is already empty, you can try enter 'latest' there to get latest unstable omnisharp (again after VSCode restart).

Comment: It is not letting me edit the settings.json. The omnisharp.path is null in the settings.json

Comment: Why can't you edit 'settings.json' - due to security?

Comment: it says you can't edit the read only editor

Comment: can I know where this settings.json be found physically on the harddisk?
can I edit from there?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problema and fixed it with:

Press Ctrl-Shift-P / Cmd-Shift-P (all keyboard shortcuts in this guide are for macOS) and then search for the command .NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug.

Then try debugging again